VBA for Index match lookup to return multiple columns by Column name.but column name is not the first column for the lookup
PS: I have edited my descrition after the first post since I get response not what I intended. mybad for not conveyed it properly..
I have a complex situation where I could not find answer in any forums so posting this  as a new question.
Basically this is a Lookup script from Sheet"Data" to my Search sheet which is ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet. I am looking to expand my existing vba script which run fine for me which return multiple values from Sheet "Data" when the search value is the first column. The issue is when the search value column name in the ActiveSheet is not in the first column it does not show any result .Search sheet is the ActiveSheet and Raw data come from Sheet name"Data". I am able to create a VBA which is as below. I would like the search based on Column header name instead of Column number. So far I have created this as below. I have attached an xlsm file for the data.Pls note if you delete first 3 rows it works.
  Sub Lookupbyheader()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim TableArray As Range, hRange As Range

      Const m = "MESSAGE", S = "Data"
      If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & S & "'!A1)") Then
         Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = S
         Application.StatusBar = "Add your search list in Sheet 'DATA' column A and 
          Proceed!!":
          Exit Sub
         Application.StatusBar = False
      Else
         Application.StatusBar = False
      End If

   Set wsED = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
   Set hRange = wsED.Range("1:1")
   Set rED = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(S)
   Set xRange = rED.Range("A:A")
   Set hdxRange = rED.Range("1:1")
   Set TableArray = rED.UsedRange.Columns

    empid = WorksheetFunction.Match("EMP ID", hRange, 0)
    ColPI = WorksheetFunction.Match("Port ID", hRange, 0)
    ColDes = WorksheetFunction.Match("Designation", hRange, 0)
    ColN = WorksheetFunction.Match("Name", hRange, 0)
    ColLoc = WorksheetFunction.Match("Location", hRange, 0)

     LastRow = wsED.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     LastCol = wsED.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

       For x = 2 To LastRow
       For y = 2 To LastCol

      On Error Resume Next
      wsED.Cells(x, y) = WorksheetFunction.Index(TableArray, _
      WorksheetFunction.Match(wsED.Cells(x, empid), xRange, 0), _
      WorksheetFunction.Match(wsED.Cells(empid, y), hdxRange, 0))

      Next y
         Next x
      
         Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     End Sub

PS: I do not mind if you suggest a more quicker vba script which can run faster and save time as I am running this search for over 10 k rows.My current script takes approx 8-10 Seconds to run the huge volume data.
Appreciate your expertise with regard to this.

Unable to upload xlsm sheet

SO doesn't support uploading Excel file. Please create MD table with online tool Table Generator for the sample data.

Set xRange = rED.Range("A:A") you need to adjust this to whatever column is being searched

Why do the work to find ColPI etc and then not use those positions?

I tired to change it to Set xRange = rED.Range("D:D") Column D is where the search value is. but does not show any result.Dont know what I am missing

Why do the work to find ColPI etc and then not use those positions? This is if the position of column " ColPI is changed in the Search tab it should still populate the result. But i think we can comment out all except the first one "empid"

What I'm taking away from your request versus what is written is that you want to find a header name and select its column (.find()' & '.column).
Also noted is the use of on error resume next, which ignores an error that should most likely be addressed (if not foundValue is nothing then).
I would posit the below mock-up script to help streamline finding and doesn't require the worksheet functions:
with sheets(1)
    dim outputRange as range:  set outputRange = .rows(1).find("OutputHeaderName")
    if not outputRange is nothing then
       dim outputColumn as long:  outputColumn = outputRange.column
       dim lastRow as long:  .cells(.rows.count,outputColumn).end(xlup).com
       dim headerArray as variant:  headerArray = ("Header1", "Header2") 
       dim i as long:  for i = lbound(headerArray) to ubound(headerArray)
           dim headerFound as range:  set headerFound = .rows(1).find(headerArra(i))
           if not headerFound is nothing then
               'do something
           else
               msgbox "Header " & headerArray(i) & " not found."
           end if
       next i
    else
        msgbox "Output range header not found."
    end if
end with


This mock-up just helps get to the end faster.  You already know what you're working to output from, so why are you using a worksheet function when you can just value = cells(rownum,outputColumn).value`, considering you're doing other loops, etc.  Mostly food for thought, where the error are being called out and accounted.

Dear Cyril. Source data comes from Sheet"Data"  and Lookup is done in the ActiveSheet on sheet1.The reason i have "on error resume next" is to ignore  populating the columns  where there is no match for the column name values with Sheet"Data" and populates only for the column names  where the name is matching with Source. I have few columns in between matching column which does not match with Source sheet.

@user2392568 the resume error is exactly why i set it up this way.  If you find the correct column, you're not iterating and attempting to perform that action for every single cell, regardless of error.  This leads to if not headerFound is nothing then // dim headerColumn as long:  headerColumn = headerFound.Column and you can then collect the data... if you need to store multiple, you can create a second array and store values, or just keep them as constants for utilization.

Dear Cyril, As I checked the above script wondering where does it say its fetching the data from Sheet"Data" Basically its a look up from Sheet"Data" to the ActiveSheet based on column header name. My script only works if the Lookup key column position is in the first but does not work if its 2nd or 3rd.So trying to update this script  based on column name. thanks again..

@user2392568 .rows(1).find(headerArra(i)) does utilize the first row in my example, where you can go back and specify a single row or could just search across all .Cells.Find(headerArra(i)).  In case something is ever duplicated, that becomes a problem, where specifying a row or column tends to control the system in an intended manner to prevent that from happening.

I think what you want to do is

Run a search against a dataset using a list from sheet "Data"
Search should match on the specific header used on "Data" (in A1)
On making a match, return only specific named columns from the dataset and add them on "Data" next to the search value.

Here's one suggestion for how you could do it (tested and working for me)  It could be made faster if you're OK with just transferring the values and you don't need formatting etc to carry over to "Data"
Sub Lookupbyheader()
    
    Const WS_LIST As String = "Data" 'sheet name where user pastes list of items to search for
    
    Dim wsList As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, wb As Workbook, c As Range, v, m
    Dim colEmpId As Variant, listCount As Long, rngList As Range, rngData As Range
    Dim dictHeaders As Object, hdr As String, el, arrHeaders, i As Long, colMatch As Long
    Dim First As Boolean

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set wsData = ActiveSheet 'or some specific named worksheet
    Set rngData = wsData.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'data table
    Set dictHeaders = HeaderMap(rngData.Rows(1)) 'collect headers from first row
    
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error(s) if sheet is missing
    Set wsList = wb.Worksheets(WS_LIST)
    listCount = Application.CountA(wsList.Range("A2:A1000"))
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    
    'OK to proceed?
    If wsList Is Nothing Or listCount = 0 Then
        If wsList Is Nothing Then wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = WS_LIST
        MsgBox "First add your search list in Sheet '" & _
                WS_LIST & "' column A and Proceed!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub 'nothing to search for yet....
    End If
    
    'header to match on should be in A1 of "Data", eg "EMP ID"
    hdr = wsList.Range("A1").Value
    'no header, or header not matched on data sheet?
    If Len(hdr) = 0 Or Not dictHeaders.Exists(hdr) Then
        MsgBox "Required header in A1 of '" & WS_LIST & _
           "' must match a column header on '" & wsData.Name & "' !", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    'columns to be retrieved on searching
    arrHeaders = Array("Port ID", "Designation", "Name", "Location")
    
    colMatch = dictHeaders(hdr) 'the column to match on
    Set rngList = wsList.Range("A2:A" & wsList.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    First = True
    For Each c In rngList.Cells 'loop over the search list
        v = c.Value
        If Len(v) > 0 Then
            'find matching row in EmpId column
            m = Application.Match(v, rngData.Columns(colMatch), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                i = 1
                For Each el In arrHeaders
                    If dictHeaders.Exists(el) Then
                        If First Then wsList.Cells(1, 1 + i) = el 'add the header on first match
                        rngData.Cells(m, dictHeaders(el)).Copy c.Offset(0, i)
                        'this would be faster:
                        'c.Offset(0, i).Value = rngData.Cells(m, dictHeaders(el)).Value
                        i = i + 1 'next paste location
                    Else
                        If First Then Debug.Print "Missing header: " & el
                    End If
                Next el
                First = False 'done with first match
            Else
                Debug.Print "Not matched: " & v
            End If
        End If
        
    Next c
End Sub

'Return a Scripting Dictionary linking headers to column position
Function HeaderMap(rw As Range) As Object
    Dim n, dict As Object, k, c As Range
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = 1 'vbTextCompare: case-insensitive
    For Each c In rw.Cells
        k = CStr(c.Value) 'string keys are faster to add?
        If Len(k) > 0 Then dict.Add k, c.Column
    Next c
    Set HeaderMap = dict
End Function


Hello Tim. thanks for the time spent on my request. Unfortunately the script is not pulling any result for me. I am not seeing anything is updated in the ActiveSheet from the Sheet("Data") .Please note I have columns which are not matching in between the matching columns in my ActiveSheet  so it should be ignored ( blank) while running the script

Can you share some screenshots of your data and of the final state of the sheet "Data"?  That would help us understand exactly what you're trying to do.

See updated code above
